# expo bare workflow can't use nativemodule

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, react-native-firebase

Am new to expo. I want to use NativeModules in expo bare flow but am not able to use NativeModules am getting **undefined** error. So Am getting doubt on does expo bare flow support Native Modules are not?

I initially created an expo project with a comment **expo init my-project** blank project then I did some changes in app.js after I want to use the project as a bare flow. Then I eject the project using this comment **expo eject** after the eject is not able to use NativeModules with native plugins like React Native Firebase https://rnfirebase.io, applozic, etc.

Please tell me you am not able to use NativeModules in expo bare flow.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from EXPO SDK 42, You can detach managed Expo to  Expo Custom Client, with Expo Custom Client, you can install any native modules you want and rebuild new Expo Client with your native modules embedded.

Some native modules, require changing the platform-specific settings, (build.gradle, Info.plist files, and more). Expo exposes [Config Plugins API](https://blog.expo.dev/introducing-custom-development-clients-5a2c79a9ddf8) to do those custom configurations.

On top of that, Expo has a new [Expo Application Service (EAS)](https://blog.expo.dev/introducing-custom-development-clients-5a2c79a9ddf8) which builds your app on Expo servers without the need to build on your local devices and stay free from complex native development setup.

Popular packages like `react-native-firebase` provide their own config Plugin out of the box and Expo Team is maintaining config plugins for common used [libraries](https://github.com/expo/config-plugins).

With all tools and infrastructure, you don't need to eject Expo for sake of using native modules.